# How to change rotation of the color ramp on the cylinder

Tags: node-editor

I'm using the mapping rotation to change orientation of the black and white streaks, but nothing is happening. I need them to go the way the arrow is pointing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup clearly **does work**:

[image]

All 3 axes work, so it's not about applying the rotation:

[image]

Your problem comes down to 2 things:

1. You multiply the $z$ coordinates by $0$. This means you flatten your coordinate space to 2D. Imagine that you have a rotating square, but you flatten it to 0 on Z axis - no longer resembles something rotating, does it?

[image]

2. You're multiplying your coordinate space twice, first inside the Mapping node (by a lot) and then again considerably in Noise Texture (*Scale* input does just that, multiplies all coordinates coming in). This means neighboring points are far from each-other on the perlin noise texture, and the further you are from another point on perlin noise, the less likely you are to be similar. So effectively you're creating a white noise. Now if you take the white noise and rotate it, you're unlikely to see it actually rotates:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to change the scale along the X axis (if the rotation is applied, otherwise the Z axis), not rotate the texture.

[image]